# How can I successfully add Bluetooth search results to an arrayadapter containing paired devices

Tags: android, android-listview, bluetooth

I am doing this application that picks all bluetooth paired devices on a phone and populates an ArrayAdapter, then it searches for bluetooth devices in range and also updates the arrayAdapter. But I am getting an error when I try running this app.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

ListView JlistView1;
BluetoothAdapter btAdpter;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
Set<BluetoothDevice> devicesArray;
ArrayList<String> pairedDevices;
ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices;
IntentFilter filter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUP();
    bluetoothStatus();
    gettingPairedDevices();
    startingDiscovering();
    searchDevicesInrange();
}

public void setUP() {
    // setting up user interface
    pairedDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
    devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    JlistView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    btAdpter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pairedDevices);
    JlistView1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    JlistView1.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void bluetoothStatus() {
    if (btAdpter == null) {
        // there is not driver
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "There is no bluetooth adapter", 0).show();
        finish();
    } else {
        if (btAdpter.isEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is enabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {

            enablingBluetooth();
        }
    }
}

public void enablingBluetooth() {
    Intent filter = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(filter), 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Bluetooth must be enabled to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        finish();
    }

}

public void gettingPairedDevices() {
    devicesArray = btAdpter.getBondedDevices();
    if (devicesArray.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : devicesArray) {
            pairedDevices.add(device.getName());
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (btAdpter.isDiscovering()) {
        btAdpter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    String device = pairedDevices.get(arg2).toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your selected " + device,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void searchDevicesInrange() {
    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(RangReciever, filter);

    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    registerReceiver(RangReciever, filter);

    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(RangReciever, filter);

    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(RangReciever, filter);

}

BroadcastReceiver RangReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // if devices found
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            devices.add(device);
            pairedDevices.add(device.getName() + " new");

        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {

        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED
                .equals(action)) {

        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {

            if (btAdpter.getState() == btAdpter.STATE_OFF) {// turn on
                                                            // bluetooth
                                                            // again
                enablingBluetooth();
            }
        }

    }
};

public void startingDiscovering() {
    btAdpter.cancelDiscovery();
    btAdpter.startDiscovery();
}
```

Logcat output

```
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463): Activity com.jingo.bluetoothjingo.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.jingo.bluetoothjingo.MainActivity$1@4051f108 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.jingo.bluetoothjingo.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.jingo.bluetoothjingo.MainActivity$1@4051f108 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:799)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:575)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:857)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:844)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:838)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:318)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at com.jingo.bluetoothjingo.MainActivity.searchDevicesInrange(MainActivity.java:114)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at com.jingo.bluetoothjingo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1785)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1842)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-09 14:00:57.430: E/ActivityThread(1463):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: i have added the error below the code

Answer (score 0):

In your `SearchDevicesInRange()` you are registering the `IntentReceiver`s multiple times without calling `unRegister()`. You should be able to use `filter.addAction(...)` to add to the receiver instead of creating new receivers if you need all of these. **[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577566/android-leaked-intentreceiver-exception-is-being-thrown-even-though-i-call-unre)** talks about this issue and you may find **[These Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#addAction(java.lang.String))** helpful, also. I hope this helps.