# jSoup.connect(url).get() gives an error Exception Android Application

Tags: java, android, multithreading, cordova, jsoup

`jSoup.connect(url).get()` gives an error Exception in my Android Application. URL working fine on Browsers or hit URL with 'HTTPCLIENT' but when i access it through jsoup it throws an exception in android.

```
public class PracticeDetailsRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<JSONObject>>{

public LoginActivity activity;
PracticeDetailsRequest(LoginActivity context)
{
    activity = context;
} 

@Override
protected ArrayList<JSONObject> doInBackground(String... value) {

    string url= "http://cmdlhravn01/ChargeCapture/Authentication/ChargeCaptureLogin?username=bilbl786&password=2ac9da7dc0243c0083eb70898e549b63&practiceid=1&userid=78&locationid=2&DBName=MUII_CureMD&DBServerName=cmdlhrnavqa01";
    jSoup.connect(url).get();
}
}
```

Exceptions:

```
    05-26 17:31:05.589: E/ActivityThread(22045): Activity com.example.avalon.LoginActivity has leaked IntentReceiver org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView$1@41e6bdd0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    05-26 17:31:05.589: E/ActivityThread(22045): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.example.avalon.LoginActivity has leaked IntentReceiver org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView$1@41e6bdd0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    05-26 17:31:05.589: E/ActivityThread(22045):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:805)
```

Comment: actually what you should you try ?

Comment: @AmitPrajapati I need html source code in my string object. you can hit the url in browser and check that it is working fine on browser but on code it is giving an error

Comment: for me it is working fine may be its a server proxy from my company...

Answer (score 1):

You need to `unregisterReceiver()` in the `onPause()` method. Then you can re-register it in the `onRestart()` method.

More information here: 
[Android: Leaked IntentReceiver exception is being thrown even though I call unregisterReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577566/android-leaked-intentreceiver-exception-is-being-thrown-even-though-i-call-unre)

Comment: it is working good with HttpClient.Execute but it only gives me the error on Jsoup.connect