# Unregistering Broadcast Receiver error

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to get the available bluetooth devices in my android app so as i can pair or unfair a device through my app. I am registering a broadcast receiver to inform my list of new devices. I do this in an activity, but when i destroy my activity with `finish()` even though i am unregistering the receiver it keeps giving me the following error.

**Exception:**

```
03-10 10:24:48.790 25219-25219/com.vidame E/ActivityThread: Activity com.vidame.Activities.BloodPressureActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.vidame.HelperClasses.Bluetooth$mPairReceiver@37341ff5 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.vidame.Activities.BloodPressureActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.vidame.HelperClasses.Bluetooth$mPairReceiver@37341ff5 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:904)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:705)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1685)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1665)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1659)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:495)
    at com.vidame.HelperClasses.Bluetooth.registerBluetoothBroadcast(Bluetooth.java:83)
    at com.vidame.Activities.BloodPressureActivity$2.onClick(BloodPressureActivity.java:119)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4789)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19881)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

My have my `broadcast receiver` method in **Bluetooth.java** class with other useful methods i use in my app and call it in `BloodPressureActivity`. Below i have code for both these classes

This is where i register the receiver in `BloodPressureActivity`

```
devices_list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            bluetooth.registerBluetoothBroadcast(BloodPressureActivity.this, mAdapter, list, mProgressDlg, mListView);
            device_find.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            devices_list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            list_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bluetooth.bAdapter().startDiscovery();
        }
    });
```

> and i unregister it in my onDestroy() and onStop()

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    bluetooth.unRegisterReceiver();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    bluetooth.unRegisterReceiver();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Now in the Bluetooth.class my broadcast receiver

```
 public void registerBluetoothBroadcast (Activity parent, DeviceListAdapter mAdapter, ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> list, ProgressDialog mProgressDlg, ListView mListView){
    this.activity=parent;
    this.mAdapter=mAdapter;
    this.list=list;
    this.mProgressDlg=mProgressDlg;
    this.mListView=mListView;

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    //filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
    activity.registerReceiver(mPairReceiver, filter);
}


public final BroadcastReceiver mPairReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);
            final int prevState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);

            if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED && prevState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                ShowMessage("Paired");
            } else if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE && prevState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                ShowMessage("Unpaired");
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            mProgressDlg.show();
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            mProgressDlg.dismiss();
            showDevicesList(list);
        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            list.add(device);
            ShowMessage("Found device " + device.getName());
        }
    }
};

public void unRegisterReceiver(){
    if(mPairReceiver!=null){
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(activity).unregisterReceiver(mPairReceiver);
    }
}
```

Is there something the i am missing about unregistered the receiver?

Comment: while unregistering you need to pass the context, and use that context to unregister . bluetooth.unRegisterReceiver(this);

Comment: Remove `onStop` function. Your receiver is unregistered twice.

Comment: i am passing the context of my activity in Bluetooth.class when i create in like this `bluetooth.setActivity(BloodPressureActivity.this);` . It is the activity value of `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(activity).unregisterReceiver(mPairReceiver);` in my unregister of Bluetooth.class

Comment: check out this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577566), maybe the problem is similar to yours

Comment: ... and if this did not help: how often is the Button clicked. i.e. how often do you register the receiver? If you click three times and unregister twice, then this could be an explanation for the error. Another thought: what happens if you make the receiver static? see [this blog](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are unregistering it twice, in your `onDestroy()` and in `onStop()`.
If you are registering your broadcast in your onCreate method, you must unregister it in `onDestroy` and if you are registering it in `onStart` you must unregister it in `onStop`.
In your case, you are registering the broadcast in a clickListener, so if the user doesn't click on this button, the broadcast is not registered and you are trying to unregister it after that. so you must do a test if the broadcast is registered.
I advise you to add a boolean attribute and when the user click on this button you set this attribute to `true` once you are in `onDestroy` you test on this boolean if it is true you unregister your broadcast.

```
devices_list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            bluetooth.registerBluetoothBroadcast(BloodPressureActivity.this, mAdapter, list, mProgressDlg, mListView);
            registred = true;
            device_find.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            devices_list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            list_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bluetooth.bAdapter().startDiscovery();
        }
    });

onDestroy{
...//your code
if(registred){
unregisterBroadcast(your broadcast);
}

}
```

Comment: still gives me the same error! I have done the check in onDestroy and onPause before unregistering the receiver and in onResume before registering it again.